# ExtJS 4.x: how to add a contol (i.e. Button) to XTemplate-based View

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm going to make a Twitter-like component, which contains a list of excerpts. In the picture I highlighted the first excerpt. It should contain several action buttons:

[image: Ext.view.View]

The problem is that XTemplate does not allow to use components as a parameter. The following code shows string `[object Object]` instead of button:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div>{[createButton()]}</div>',
    '</tpl>',
    {
        createButton: function() {
            return new Ext.Button(text:'Button')
        }
    }
);
```

How can I insert buttons into every excerpt?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use components. If possible, use simple icons, preferably from an [icon font](http://extjs.eu/using-font-icons-in-ext-fontawesome/). Configuration of such icons can be easily generated by XTemplate. Also, it is not too difficult to style the icons based on values from record (disabled look, colored look, etc.)

For interaction, listen to the container, identify which icon has been clicked and execute the appropriate action.

No need of components here.

Comment: I like answers like "you do not need what you are asking for". In plain English it means that ExtJS does not support this feature. Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: I thought you want a solution, not XTemplate to support components. And yes, it's not supported and I doubt it ever will be.